# Default value of a function pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

What is the default value of a function pointer in C++? (Apparently it can't be `NULL`, so what is it?)

How is this program supposed to behave and why?

```
struct S { void (*f)(); };

int main()
{
    S s = S();
    s.f();   // What is the value of s.f?
}
```

Comment: *(Apparently it can't be `NULL`, ...)*. Why?

Comment: @Nawaz: My understanding was that function pointers cannot be `NULL`... am I wrong?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, you're wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Pubby: I could almost swear I came across some piece of code a while ago that said something along the lines of "since function pointers can't be null, we have to make a default handler" or something of that sort... I guess I misunderstood then?

Comment: @Mehrdad it certainly sounds like it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Or that piece of code was wrong. *Any* pointer can be null.

Comment: @Angew: Hmm... *any* pointer? So you mean even *member* function pointers can be null?

Comment: @Mehrdad maybe it was handling the corner case when the pointer was NULL? i.e. call default handler when pointer points to no function.

Comment: @Pubby: Possibly, though that wasn't my impression when I saw it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes. Object pointers, function pointers, data member pointers, member function pointers, `void*`, all can be null. That's why unlike C, in C++ the macro `NULL` **cannot** be defined as `((void*)0)`, which wouldn't be assignable into member pointers.

Comment: @Mehrdad Even member pointers.  And to be precise, a pointer can be null; it cannot be `NULL` (which is a null pointer constant, which curiously enough, is _not_ a pointer).

Comment: @Angew The reason the macro `NULL` cannot be defined as `((void*)0)` is because the C++ standard says it can't.  `0` has type `int`, and except for special wording, couldn't be assigned to any pointer.  `((void*)0)` has type `void*`, and except for special wording in the C standard, could not be assigned to a function pointer in C.  Both standards contain special language to allow null pointer constants to break the type system.  C++ uses the traditional definition; for some reason, the C committee extended the legal types in a null pointer constant.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know you can't assign `NULL` to function pointers!

Comment: @Mehrdad You can assign `NULL` to any pointer, because it meets the special definition of a null pointer constant (an integral constant expression evaluating to 0).  This is a very special (magic?) conversion, since it only works if the expression is constant, and only for one specific value.  (Note that `int i = 0; void* p = reinterpret_cast<void*>( i );` may result in something different than `void* p = 0;`.)

Comment: Stroustrup says somewhere that there is never any need for NULL in a properly written C++ program. Zero always suffices.

Comment: @JamesKanze On a deep enough level, you are right indeed. In the level of casual usage, I believe my explanation to be a bit more understandable.

Comment: @EJP While there's technically no need, it can help code readability in certain contexts. That is, assuming you consistently use `NULL` for all null pointer values and *only* for null pointer values.

Comment: @Angew Except that your explination is completely false.  There is no fundamental reason why `((void*)0)` could not have been made a null pointer constant, as it is in C, except tradition.  It works as well as `0`.  Without the special rules, you couldn't assign `0` to _any_ pointer.

Comment: @Angew I agree with you about using `NULL`, there are valid arguments for both sides (which is why `nullptr` was added to the language).  Given `template <typename T> void f( T );`, some people find it surprising that `f( NULL )` instantiates the template for `int`.  If your coding style makes extensive use of (abuses?) templates and function overloading, you may prefer using `0` as the null pointer; if it doesn't you may prefer `NULL` (as I do).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, my comment applies to C++03 of course. In C++11, one should only use `nullptr` as the null pointer constant.

Comment: *"default value of a function pointer"* - Like any other primitive type, **indeterminate**. *zero-initialized value* (which seems the one you're after here), though - null pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case the object `s` is zero-initialized which means the function pointer is `NULL`.

```
struct S { void (*f)(); };

int main()
{
    S s = S();
    if ( s.f == NULL)
       std::cout << "s.f is NULL" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
s.f is NULL
```

[Online demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e8c6c3e1874a2c1883c50da3589a59a2).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, made my life easier choosing between them! xD

Answer (score 18):

First *any* pointer can be null. It is the one universal truth about pointers. That said, yours *will* be null, but not necessarily for the reasons you may think;

> **C++11 § 8.5,p10**
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., **()**, shall be **value-initialized**.

This is important because your declaration includes this :

```
S s = S();
```

By the definition of *value initialization*:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p7**
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is **zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized.**

Which brings us to what it means for your object-type to be zero-initialized:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p5**
>
> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T <sub>(103)</sub>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, **each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized** and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero- initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> 103) As specified in 4.10, converting an integral constant expression whose value is 0 to a pointer type results in a **null pointer value**.

The latter is the reason you're pointer is null. It will *not* be guaranteed-so by the standard given the same code, but changing the declaration of `s` to this:

```
S s;
```

Given a declaration like the above, a different path is taken through the standard:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p11**
>
> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is **default-initialized**; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2.

Which then begs the last question, what is *default initialization*:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p6**
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Comment: Oh well, 'A' for effort :-)

Comment: I was aware of the initialization actually, that's why I did it... but +1 for mentioning it anyway lol.

Comment: A whole bunch of Standard quotes just to say "The default value of a function pointer is NULL"?

Comment: @Puppy Its not that it *can* be NULL; its how it *got* there. It got there by initialization, and the method of initialization is paramount to its final value. If what you said verbatim were universally true, "the default value of a function pointer is NULL", it wouldn't matter. Its not, so it does.

Answer (score 3):

Function pointer can be NULL, this way you can indicate that they don't point to anything!

Answer (score 3):

A function pointer can be NULL and you may assign NULL to it. Have a look [here](http://ideone.com/5COrgw) for instance:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S { void (*f)(); };

int main()
{
    S s = S();
    s.f = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the way you call the constructor of the structure(with `()`), f will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and C), pointers (regardless of type) do not have a default value *per se*; they take what ever happens to be in memory at the time. However, they do have a default initialised value of `NULL`.

#### Default Initialisation

When you don't explicitly define a constructor, C++ will call the default initialiser on each member variable, which will initialise pointers to `0`. However, if you define a constructor, but do not set the value for a pointer, it does not have a default value. The behaviour is the same for integers, floats and doubles.

**Aside**

```
int main()
{
    S s = S();
    s.f();   // <-- This is calling `f`, not getting the pointer value.
}
```

Comment: Huh? I thought if I say `struct P { void *p; }; P p = P();` then `p.p` must be `NULL`, must it not?

Comment: @Mehrdad I will try to clarify.

Comment: @Alex: `S s;` and `S s = S();` are two **different* things! Note that `S` is POD.