# Why will std::sort crash if the comparison function is not as operator <?

Tags: c++, algorithm, exception, standards

The following program is compiled with VC++ 2012.

```
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    A()
        : a()
    {}

    bool operator <(const A& other) const
    {
        return a <= other.a;
    }

    int a;
};

int main()
{
    A coll[8];
    std::sort(&coll[0], &coll[8]); // Crash!!!
}
```

If I change `return a <= other.a;` to `return a < other.a;` then the program runs as expected with no exception.

Why?

Comment: The comparator for `std::sort` requires a strict weak ordering, which `<=` does *not* supply.

Comment: You should write a(0) for the A ctor... but it does not crash here anyways!

Comment: @WhozCraig: The default constructor initializes them to zero.

Comment: @GManNickG I see that now. thanks for catching it.

Comment: @GManNickG, no, it does not. Not deterministically, that is.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Yes it does. It value-initializes `a()` (that's what `a()` means), which for `int` means 0.

Comment: GManNickG: mind backing up with the standard material?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259602/default-values-in-c-initializer-lists

Comment: @LaszloPapp a dissection of value-initialization vs. default initialization can also be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829158/default-value-of-a-function-pointer-in-c), though as a pointer rather than an `int`.

Comment: GManNickG: thanks! That is what I also guessed after your initial write, but I thought it is better to double check with the standard, but I did not have enough time to open it up. :) By the way, it is off-topic, but I think it makes more sense to be explicit, and initialize it to zero explicitly.

Comment: Please replace the undefined behavior &coll[8] by coll + 8

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`std::sort` requires a sorter which satisfies the **strict weak ordering** rule, which is explained 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981299/2632282)

So, your comparer says that `a < b`when `a == b` which doesn't follow the **strict weak ordering** rule, it is possible that the algorithm will crash because it'll enter in an infinite loop.

Comment: +1 This states the requirements of `std::sort`'s comparator well. I would follow this with using `std::sort(std::begin(coll), std::end(coll));` if your compiler is compliant with C++11 (and the OPs *is* compliant; VS2012). If you ever change the dimensions of your array, or instead use any of the standard containers, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: Entering an infinite loop should just cause it to get stuck.  Instead it dumps core.  Why?

Comment: @btilly I think because `std::sort` uses a recursive algorithm which will cause a stack overflow in case of an infinite loop.

Comment: You'd have to get into specifics of what it checks, but the standard sort routines are intended to run very, very fast, so they don't check everything you do to see if it's okay, they just rely on it.  If your comparisons are returning impossible results then impossible things are going to happen -- say it's got the results of some comparison and it's using that as an index for where to look, only it "knows" what values are possible and "knows" the resulting reference will be in valid storage so it just fetches it.  Kaboom: SIGSEGV with any luck.  With bad luck, it'll silently hose your data.

Answer (score 11):

The answer for xorguy is pretty good.

I would just add some quote from the standard :

> **25.4 Sorting and related operations [alg.sorting]**
>
> For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work correctly, **comp has to induce a *strict weak ordering* on the values.**
>
> The term *strict* refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (!comp(x, x) for all x), and the term *weak* to requirements that are not as strong as those for a total ordering, but stronger than those for a partial ordering.

So xorguy explains it very well : You `comp` function says that `a < b` when `a == b` which doesn't follow the **strict weak ordering** rule...

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your code is that you are accessing invalid memory. Code

```
coll[8]
```

trying to access the element after the last array element (the last element index is 7).
I would suggest using std::array instead plain C arrays.

```
std::array<A, 8> a;

// fill it somehow

std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
```