# Compare function in c++ stl sort

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to obtain an non-increasing order from a given random ordered elements.After working a lot, I realized that both the following codes produce different outputs. Why the codes produce different outputs?

```
bool cmp(int i,int j)
{
    if(i<j)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
bool cmp(int i,int j)
{
   return i>j;
}
```

Comment: @pranitkothari No they are different. Although they may end up producing similar results in sorting.

Comment: I was working on a SPOJ problem. I used the first code and my program was not accepted. I used the second code and my program was accepted.

Comment: I worked on many test cases and both the codes produced same outputs.Could someone provide me better test cases?

Comment: @tharun here's your program with different output: http://ideone.com/MDwgGy

Answer (score 2):

First function should be

```
bool cmp(int i,int j)
{
    if(i>j)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

to get equivalent outputs.

Or alternatively use the following function:

```
bool cmp(int i,int j)
{
    return -1 * i < -1 * j;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide me with a test case where both of my codes produce  different outputs?

Comment: Yes, when both are equal.

Comment: Could you provide me with a test case where both of MY codes produce different outputs?

Comment: There may be multiple possibilities to mess up. So not without looking at the rest of the code.

Comment: @tharun you should not get a difference in normal (unstable) sorting, but in stable sorting (i.e., where the order of equivalent elements matter)

Comment: @MohitJain - Assuming the OP means `std::sort`, your answer doesn't seem correct in terms of what `std::sort` requires.  The `>=` is not a strict-weak-ordering, which std::sort uses.  For example, Visual Studio checks for things like this, and I believe your code will cause an assertion in debug builds.

Comment: But if I use these codes in the same program, one leads to wrong answer and other leads to accepted answer.Why?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you give me a pair where strict-weak-ordering fails?

Comment: @tharun - Are you using std::sort?  If so, then the reason is what I stated in my comment.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie good point, @tharun related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18291620/3093378

Comment: @MohitJain - It is not correct in terms of strict-weak-ordering.  If I give your compare function two values, and you return `true` that the first comes before the second value, then I call your compare function again, but switch the values on you.  You again return `true`.  Guess what?  You lose.  How can I give you a,b and you return `true` and at the same time, give you b,a and you still return true?  That is the exact test that Visual Studio does to ensure the strict-weak-order is maintained.

Comment: @MohitJain - Correct, but the thing that messes your answer up is that dreaded `>=`.  That operator has been the downfall of many a C++ programmer implementing a compare function for std::sort.  You can also add `<=` to this list.  Stick with `<` or `>` when implementing the compare function.

Comment: Could you provide me with the related references (or) is it fine if I refer to earlier strict weak ordering link?

Comment: @tharun - the link provided by `vsoftco` is ok.

Comment: @MohitJain - Please update your answer with the correct strict weak ordering.  It sill uses `<=`, which will throw off the sort.  See the link that `vsoftco` provided to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

#### First things first:

Your two functions produce different results when they have the same input. So `cmp(1,1)` produces different results.

#### Undefined behavior:

Given this `cmp()` function:

```
bool cmp(int i,int j) {
    if(i<j)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

The following statement will produce **undefined behavior**:

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(), cmp);
```

The comparator passed to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is required to implement [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). One of the requirements is that `cmp(1,1)` will return false. Your code returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Your first function is equivalent to "not less than" i.e. "greater or equal" when what you want is "greater". Also, given that this is C++11, why not just do:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Comment: Ahh... right... late night commenting and for some reason I saw "since c++14" in the docs and missed the line before saying "until c++14". Updated.