# C++ program not working for large input (logic_error, _M_construct null not valid)

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm trying to implement the maximizing salary problem. Like if we are given two numbers `2` and `21` then the resultant number should be `221` not `212`. I implemented the code and it works very well for small inputs. The code uses C++ `std::sort` with a simple comparator function. For big inputs like for 100 it fails and gives following error.

```
stderr:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::max;


bool comp(const string &a, const string &b) {
  string combo1 = a+b;
  string combo2 = b+a;
  return combo1>=combo2;
}

string largest_number(vector<string> a) {
  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comp);
  string result = "";
  for (int i=0; i< a.size(); i++) {
    result = result + a[i];
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<string> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cin >> a[i];
  }
  std::cout << largest_number(a);
}
```

For the following inputs it gives error.

`100`

`2 8 2 3 6 4 1 1 10 6 3 3 6 1 3 8 4 6 1 10 8 4 10 4 1 3 2 3 2 6 1 5 2 9 8 5 10 8 7 9 6 4 2 6 3 8 8 9 8 2 9 10 3 10 7 5 7 1 7 5 1 4 7 6 1 10 5 4 8 4 2 7 8 1 1 7 4 1 1 9 8 6 5 9 9 3 7 6 3 10 8 10 7 2 5 1 1 9 9 5`

How do I solve this issue? I read some probable solutions and it was something about NULL pointers which I couldn't understand.

Comment: Your comparator function is wrong, see the [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). For instance, `comp("a","a")` is `true`, which does not define _strict weak ordering_.

Comment: Yes! right! This is something which I did wrong. Didn't knew. These online tutorials don't teach about all this, they give only syntax and example. To have complete insight one should always read the documentation. You please post your answer I'll give it a green tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparator function does not meet the requirements. Namely, it does not define *strict weak ordering*. See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for more details.

For example, `comp(s,s)` must be `false`, while in your code, calling `comp` with the same argument always yields `true`. Basically, you may not use `>=` or `<=` when defining a comparator.

Relatdet question: [Why will std::sort crash if the comparison function is not as operator <?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18291620/580083)