# How can I sort a vector<pair<pair<float, float>, unsigned int>> by the first float, and if there's a tie the second float?

Tags: c++, key-value, priority-queue, heap

I have a priority queue with 'keys' that currently looks like this:

```
using HeapKey = pair<Cost, Cost>;
vector<pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>> U;
```

I insert in the queue with this command:

```
push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
```

And I have a sorting command like this:

```
struct KeyCompare {
  bool operator()(const pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& a, const pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& b) const
  {
    return a.first > b.first;
  }
};
```

I haven't worked with heaps very much, and my inexperience shows. I've read that heaps traditionally works by having the largest element first. I need the smallest.
But I also need the queue to be sorted by lexicographical order so that a key is less than or equal to another key if:

```
(k1.first <= k2.first) OR (k1.first == k2.first AND k1.second <= k2.second)
```

And I wonder how exactly I code that in C++? Currently my code doesn't seem to work a 100% since mostly get the smallest element defined by the k1.first, but not always, and I need to implement that check of the second element if two keys are equal so I can sort my priority queue.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Sorry about the lack of code. Took me a little while but I think I have a good example with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

using Cost = float;
using HeapKey = pair<Cost, Cost>;
vector<pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>> U;

struct KeyCompare {
  bool operator()(const pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& a, const pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& b) const
  {
    return a.first > b.first;
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<Cost, Cost> const& p) {
  return os << "<" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ">";
}
 
int main()
{
    U.push_back({ {5.62843, 2.8}, 1 });
    U.push_back({ {5.64264, 1.4}, 2 });
    U.push_back({ {6.01976, 1}, 3 });
    U.push_back({ {6.2, 5.2}, 4 });
    U.push_back({ {6.03607, 3.8}, 5 });
    U.push_back({ {6.03607, 3.8}, 6 });
    U.push_back({ {7.45028, 3.8}, 13 });
    U.push_back({ {7.45028, 3.8}, 14 });
    U.push_back({ {7.45028, 3.8}, 15 });
    U.push_back({ {5.62843, 1}, 16 });
    U.push_back({ {5.02843, 7.8}, 17 });
    push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());

    cout << "U: ";
    for (auto p : U) {
        cout << p.second << p.first << " - ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pop_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
        U.pop_back();
        cout << U.front().second << U.front().first << endl;
    }
}
```

So, what I get from this is:

```
U: 17<5.02843, 7.8> - 1<5.62843, 2.8> - 3<6.01976, 1> - 4<6.2, 5.2> - 2<5.64264, 1.4> - 6<6.03607, 3.8> - 13<7.45028, 3.8> - 14<7.45028, 3.8> - 15<7.45028, 3.8> - 16<5.62843, 1> - 5<6.03607, 3.8> - 
1<5.62843, 2.8>
2<5.64264, 1.4>
16<5.62843, 1>
3<6.01976, 1>
6<6.03607, 3.8>
```

And the problem I believe I'm having is, as you can see, that after I pop elements 17 I have element 1 as the next. However, element 16's first key is of equal size and it's second key is smaller, so I would like that to go first.

Furthermore element 2 comes before element 16 and 16's first key is smaller than element 2's first key, so that's not right.

Hope this is better.

Comment: `a.first.first < b.first.first || ( a.first.first == b.first.first && a.first.second <= b.first.second )` ... or `a.first < b.first` (assuming `a` and `b` are `std::pair<std::pair<float,float>, uint>`

Comment: what is `pair<<float, float>, unsigned int>`  ? What is `Cost` ? Actually I dont understand how the title relates to the code in the quesiton. `std::pair` has an operator that does compare first then second

Comment: please post a [mcve] rather than just fragments of code

Comment: Fwiw, `<=` is almost always wrong in comparison functions that are to be used with standard algorithms/containers.

Comment: Relevant question regarding `<=` and strick weak ordering: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18291620/580083.

Comment: "less than or equal" is the wrong relation. The standard ordered containers rely on an "is ordered before" relation. `a.first < b.first`  should work the way you want since the ordering for `std::pair` is lexicographic - if it doesn't, post a [mcve].

Comment: If you use a `std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::pair<float, float>, unsigned int>>` without adding your own comparison, what does it do wrong? [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/qcKh7jjrG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using the wrong function ([`std::push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap)) to create a max heap. `push_heap` puts the last element in an already existing max heap in its correct place. Use [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) to create the heap.

  ```cpp
  std::make_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
  ```
- The comparator needs to compare the second `float` before the first and possibly also the `unsigned int` to get the job done properly. To make that easy, use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). If you for example want the smallest values extracted first:

  ```cpp
  #include <tuple>

  struct KeyCompare {
      bool operator()(const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& a,
                      const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& b) const {
          return std::tie(a.first.second, a.first.first, a.second) >
                 std::tie(b.first.second, b.first.first, b.second);
      }
  };
  ```

  The above is the same as you would get if you instead did it manually like below:

  ```cpp
  struct KeyCompare {
      bool operator()(const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& a,
                      const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& b) const {
      if(a.first.second > b.first.second) return true;
      if(a.first.second < b.first.second) return false;
      if(a.first.first > b.first.first) return true;
      if(a.first.first < b.first.first) return false;
      if(a.second > b.second) return true;
      return false;
  }
  ```

  To switch ascending/descending order, just flip the `<`/`>` operators. When you use `std::tie`, you can use members from both `a` and `b` to create each tuple. In the example below I've put `b.second` in the first and `a.second` in the last. The `float`s will then be ordered in ascending order while the `unsigned int` will be in descending order.

  ```
          return std::tie(a.first.second, a.first.first, b.second) >
                 std::tie(b.first.second, b.first.first, a.second);
  ```
- You access the wrong element when you print out the result. The value to be  popped from the heap is in `U.back()` after you've called [`std::pop_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap), not in `U.front()`. You can simply reorganize your code to do it properly:

  ```cpp
  while(not U.empty()) {
      std::cout << U.front().second << ' ' << U.front().first << '\n';
      std::pop_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
      U.pop_back();        
  }
  ```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/77h1677ah)

Comment: Thank you SO much for this very detailed and well explained answer. I've also tried ChrisMM's answer which seems to also work (by flipping the < to a >, and the <= to a >=), but while I don't exactly understand all the things that goes on, I would guess that using that solution might be flawed as compared to your solution?

Comment: @OverDemon You're welcome! I don't see how using `>=` could work properly. I'll have take a look at what ChrisMM wrote when I'm back at the computer.

Comment: @OverDemon I don't think the suggestion made by ChrisMM in a comment is working.  Can you show what you did in a similar demo that I provided? Other than that, is there anything else left unanswered that I should add to the answer?

Comment: Hi Ted. Sorry for the slow answer and thanks for your continued help.
You're correct that for the example I provided it doesn't seem to actually do anything. I got sort of excited and tried ChrisMM's solution in my own program where it seems to work, but I have to admit that I'm do not have a good overview of everything that goes on by now.
I can also so in my own program, when I add an element and it's key I use:
    push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
    make_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
And using make_heap in my example instead of push_heap seem to solve that.

Comment: It's my intention to attempt to use your method in my program (and try to understand what happens ^^) as it seems that you're got a good grasp on what goes on, so your solution is logically more solid.

Comment: Also, regarding this:
You access the wrong element when you print out the result. The value to be popped from the heap is in `U.back()` after you've called `std::pop_heap`, not in `U.front()`
I do use `U.pop_back();` as I can see.

Comment: @Lyngmo
Running tests with your code in my program, and it seems to work as I would like (only run a few tests), but I had to alter the code as such:

`struct KeyCompare {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& a,
                    const std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>& b) const {
    if(a.first.first > b.first.first) return true;
    if(a.first.first < b.first.first) return false;
    if(a.first.second > b.first.second) return true;
    if(a.first.second < b.first.second) return false;
    if(a.second > b.second) return true;
    return false;
  }
};`

Comment: @OverDemon Re: _"`pop_heap`/`pop_back`"_, yes you used both but after `pop_heap` the `front()` element is moved and is the last element in `U` and `pop_back` removes it. To access the element before removing it, use `front()` _before_ `pop_heap` as I showed - or, `pop_heap` and then use `back()` (before `U.pop_back()` - or else it's too late).

Comment: Your modified `KeyCompare` seems to extract the elements in a different order to what you described in the question - or I misunderstood the question. :-) For that order you don't even need to define your own comparison function. It already exists in the standard library and is called `std::greater`. Replace your `KeyCompare` definition with this: `using KeyCompare = std::greater<std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>>;` and see if that doesn't do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Lyngmo
Thanks for the quick reply. I'm implementing your suggestions and trying to see how it works. In regard to the key ordering, I don't think you misunderstood. It's likely me that overlooked something. I get the order from this part of a paper concerning the algorithm I'm working with [link](https://imgur.com/a/zLIKNUn).
While I at first tried to do things as in the picture, it gave a reverse result (biggest first), so I switched the < to a > and had better results. Not a good way of doing things, I know, and I'll try to analyse why, but that's why I do what I did.

Comment: @Lyngmo
`using KeyCompare = std::greater<std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>>;` seems to work perfectly. I'll continue to test, but I imagine from this point on that if something doesn't work it's probably some other part of my program. 
Thanks for all the help ^^

Comment: @OverDemon Great! You're welcome! Have you also considered using `std::priority_queue`? It would look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tr5Mx43Mj)