# Safe to use += operator to create a new std::map entry using []?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Let's say I have a `std::map<int, int>`, would it be safe to do this?

```
std::map<int, int> m_map;
m_map[0] += 1;
```

If the key `0` didn't exist in the map when I do this, how would it know what value to add `1` to?

What I'm hoping is that std::map handles this by performing an `=` instead of `+=` in the case where the value creates a new entry in the map. This would spare me from having to do:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m_map.find(0);
if(it != m_map.end()) {
    it->second += 1;
}
else {
    m_map[0] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523959/stdmap-default-value-for-build-in-type

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An element inserted into a map on invoke of `operator[]` due to a previously-unmapped key is ***value-initialized***. If you've not seen that syntax, consider the special meaning the **`()`** has in the following code snippet. The parens are important. They introduce an different trip down the initialization tree than *default-initialization*. Both are important; both are laid out by the language standard.

```
int i = int();
```

As it turns out, value initialization for scalars (including pointers) eventually succumbs to ***zero-initialization***. Though odd looking, the prior snippet value-initializes an instance of `int`, which becomes zero-initialization since `int` is a scalar, then copies it to `i`. (To be fair, there will almost certainly be some eliding, but the fundamentals are as-presented).

Regardless, due to that feature, you can rest assured when you do this:

```
m_map[0] += 1;
```

or even this:

```
++m_map[0];
```

if the index wasn't mapped prior, a value-initialized element is added, which will zero-initialize for scalars, which means you'll officially starting out with *zero*.

It is worth mentioning that a similar activity happens for *any type* with an implicitly declared constructor. Whether trivial or not, something interesting happens.

```
struct S { int a; int b; };
std::map<int, S> mymap;

++mymap[0].a;
```

Is the `a` member mapped to `0` in our container reliably `1` after the above executes? **Yes**, it is. Further, consider this:

```
struct S { int a; std::string str; };
std::map<int, S> mymap;

++mymap[0].a;
```

Now `S` has a non-trivial implicit constructor (it has to, as it must construct `str`). But is the `a` member mapped to `0` in our container *still* reliably zero-initialized (and therefore `1` after the above line)? **Yes**, it is.

If curious about the referenced different paths of initialization, [**see this question and answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829622/1322972). Or review the C++11 standard, particularly **C++11 § 8.5 Initializers, (p5,p7,p10)**. It is worth the read.

Answer (score 8):

It's guaranteed that you'll get 1 even with the shorter snippet.

The key is that `operator[]` has to create the element in the map *before* returning a reference to it, so by the time you got to `+=` the element already exists, and, if it had to be created now, with value zero (since elements of a map are value-initialized).

(incidentally, this is the reason why, when you use an `std::map` with a class type as value, it has to have a default constructor if you want to use `operator[]`, even if you assign an object to it immediately)

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is fine, new entries default to value `value_type()` which is `0` for `int`.

It still does `+=`, but `0 += 1` gives `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Map is lazily initialize with default constructor.(zero for all int)

So it `0` didn't exist in map, it would be initialized to contain value 0 and 1 would be added after `+= 1`.

So you can use upper version of code without any worries.

Quoting **Effect of calling map_obj[k]** from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)

> If k matches the key of an element in the container, the function
>   returns a reference to its mapped value.
>
> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).