# Is std::map<int, void*> ensure that a empty key return NULL?

Tags: c++

I have code as below, I had try it in MSVC2010 which works ok.

```
std::map<int, int*> fooMap;
assert(fooMap[1] == null);
```

Did C++ Standard guarantee the assert would not failed forever?

thanks.

Comment: **Exactly** as you have it here, yes, it is guaranteed. A closely [**related question can be found here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333261/safe-to-use-operator-to-create-a-new-stdmap-entry-using) (arguably a dupe).

Comment: Yes. [map::operator[\]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) inserts `T()` when the element does not exist. `T()` performs [zero initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) on pointers, which initialises them to the null pointer value.

Comment: When you say `null`, do you mean `NULL` or `0` or `nullptr`? Because in C++ there is nothing named `null`.

Answer (score 2):

When inserting into a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) using the [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) function, the data will be [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), and value initialization for pointers will make them zero (i.e. null pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>
> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Two Answer could be answered:

If you want to verify that an key is empty without create it, it'would be better to check with a itterator: `map.find(KEY) != map.end()`

If you want to create an empty row for a key in your map it would be like you specified it `map[KEY]`

Answer (score 0):

That assertion will never fire given the two lines of code that you've shown.